# A python loop that search array of strings breaks after first iteration

Tags: python, string, list

I have a file with logs. each log is located in a line. I created a function that searching the file and looking for each log as a string. I ordered the logs i wish to look for as an array / list. Currently, the function is returning true/false according to the first item in the list. for example, if i will delete item #2 which is log #2 from the file, the function will still return true because item #1 is in the file. I wish that my loop will keep run until all the items in list were searched. this is my implementation:

```
def isClassDomainPassed():
    with open(NR_log, 'r') as logfile:

        key1 = 'The application is in Class Domain tab'
        key2 = 'Inspection Sampling is open'
        key3 = 'Golden Image was chosen'
        key4 = 'Accurate Navigation was chosen'
        key5 = 'Golden Image is enabled with Accurate Navigation'
        key6 = 'Location was added to Inspection Locations List'
        key7 = 'All dies were added to Inspection Dies List'
        keys = [key1, key2, key3, key4, key5, key6, key7]

        for key in keys:
            for num, line in enumerate(logfile, 1):
                if key in line:
                    return True, print("fine")
            return False, print("not")

isClassDomainPassed()
```

Comment: The second `return` should be outside the loop.

Comment: your return statement is inside the loop. it will return after the first iteration? move it outside the loop

Comment: Also, you need to seek back to the beginning of the file each time through the outer loop.

Comment: Why do you use `enumerate()` if you're not using `num`?

Comment: Reverse the outer and inner loops. ie, for each line read, then check for all the keys.

Comment: @Barmar basically, I copied this implementation from a different code, could you suggest me a proper way to define the loop?

Comment: The different code was probably looping through two lists. A file is a generator, it gets exhausted when you reach the end.

Answer (score 2):

You can't loop through the file multiple times unless you seek back to the beginning each time. Switch the order of the loops. Then you can also replace the `key in keys` loop with `any()`.

The `False` return should be outside the loop, so you only do it if you make it through all the loops.

```
for line in logfile:
    if any(key in line for key in keys):
        print("fine")
        return True

print("not")
return False
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still facing with the same problem, the function still returning true although it's should pass the whole loop.

Comment: Do you need to match all the items in the list or any of them? My code returns true if any of them is found.

Comment: Basically, if all of them are exists, return true, if one of then is missing, return false. Anyway, I was debugging my code and figure it out, problem solved. Thanks a lot for your help Anyway  :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to check if **all** keys are included in the logfile. If yes, the function should return `True`:

```py
def isClassDomainPassed(file_name):
    with open(file_name, "r") as logfile:
        data = logfile.read()

    key1 = "The application is in Class Domain tab"
    key2 = "Inspection Sampling is open"
    key3 = "Golden Image was chosen"
    key4 = "Accurate Navigation was chosen"
    key5 = "Golden Image is enabled with Accurate Navigation"
    key6 = "Location was added to Inspection Locations List"
    key7 = "All dies were added to Inspection Dies List"

    keys = [key1, key2, key3, key4, key5, key6, key7]

    return all(k in data for k in keys)


print(isClassDomainPassed("sample.txt"))
```